# Is there a way to filter only a particular type of ServerResponse using PostProcessInterceptor?

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

PostProcessInterceptor will intercept all types of response. But in my case I have two categories of response. I have to intercept one kind and let go the other kind untouched (as a plain json string result).

Is there a way by which I skip the interception of the other response kind. May be some kind of marking? Or is there a way of doing this thing differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JAX-RS 2 you could use a [name binding](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-rev-a/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/NameBinding.html) for a [ContainerResponseFilter](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-rev-a/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseFilter.html). Define an annotation:

```
@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Special {}
```

And mark the filter:

```
@Provider
@Special
public class SpecialFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {}
```

The filter will only be executed if the resource class or method is also annotated `@Special`.

If you need to use the deprecated `PostProcessInterceptor` you can't use name binding. But a simple `if` in the `postProcess` method will do the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am using ContainerResponseFilter now.